# Does javascript store datatype information beyond the prototype?

Tags: javascript, types, prototype, prototype-programming

I am studying prototyping in Javascript, and for an experiment was trying to strip some basic objects of their information as much as possible. However, I ran into an issue in the following code segment:

```
let x = [];
Object.setPrototypeOf(x, null);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(x));
>>> [object Array]
```

My confusion here: after removing the prototype, how does `Object.prototype.toString` still know that `x` is of `Array` type? Where is this information coming from, if not any of the properties? Running `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x)` and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(x)`, I do not see any properties left on `x` which contain any path to the string `Array`. Where is this information stored?

And if this is one of those "internal slots" (although I'm not sure which it would be), is there no way to modify it? Can I at least access it directly?

Update:
Yousaf has noted that the property `String.toStringTag` is normally accessed by `Object.prototype.toString` to provide the string which goes in place of "Array" in the above example. Indeed, setting `x[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'my_string'` allows us to change the `.toString()` value. However, I think it still does not solve the mystery, as `x[Symbol.toStringTag]` is `undefined` before we set it, not containing the desired "Array" string.

Comment: Yes, JS is distinguishing some object types by their internal slots or by being an exotic object (e.g. arrays, functions etc - they have special behaviour that is not related to their properties or prototypes). You cannot modify or access these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `.toString()` is  called on any object, it creates a string of the form `[object x]` where `x` is the name of the constructor in-case of built-in constructors like `Date` and `Array`.

When `.toString()` is called, there are several steps taken and one of those steps is checking if the value of `this` inside `.toString()` is an array. If its an array, tag is set to the string `'Array'`.

From the [Spec - 19.1.3.6 Object.prototype.toString ( )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.tostring):

> 5. If isArray is true, let builtinTag be "Array".

Before ES6, when `.toString()` was called on the instances of user defined constructors, `[object Object]` was logged. ES6 provided a way to override the tag using a well-known Symbol [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag).

Comment: Hm, shouldn't we have `x[Symbol.toStringTag]` being defined in that case? It appears to be `undefined`

Comment: See the updated answer with a reference to the internal working of `toString()`.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you.